# Microsoft Azure handwritten return value not have confidence

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I use handwritten API on site
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/
，but sometime the result not correct, I wander if we have the value “confidence”. I saw the return json

"status": "Succeeded","succeeded": true,"failed": false,"finished": true,"recognitionResult": {"lines": [{"boundingBox": [  .....

not the value “confidence”.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look to the API testers, no there is no `confidence` or equivalent `score` value in the handwritten detection.

Link to the API documentation: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201

Content of a valid treatment:

- **Lines**: An array of objects, where each object represents a line of recognized text.
- **Words**: An array of objects, where each object represents a recognized word.
- **BoundingBox**: Bounding box of a recognized region, line, or word, depending on the parent object. The eight integers represent the four
  points (x-coordinate, y-coordinate) of the detected rectangle from
  the left-top corner and clockwise.
- **Text**: String value of a recognized word/line.

Answer (score 0):

The confidence score is stored in the 'words' object returned.

```
for result in data.analyze_result.read_results:
  for line in result.lines:
    print(line.text)
    print(line.bounding_box)
    for word in line.words:
      print(word.text)
      print(word.confidence)
```